# Sublime Text 2 + SublimeREPL allowing user input

Tags: sublimetext2, stdin, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'd like to set up Sublime Text 2 (or 3 if recommended) to allow user input (raw_input() or input() within the files.). To clarify, I've had this work before! I want to be able to write and execute all code within one window/tab. I have installed sublimeREPL correctly but yet whenever I use either raw_input() or input() I receive the following error:

```
EOFERROR: EOF when reading a line
```

I've had it setup correctly and it worked perfectly before, but it's been a long time and I cannot reproduce the steps anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

To summarize, this works:

```
print "This is a test"
```

This will not work: (this has worked previously on my home desktop)

```
print "This is a test"
testvar = raw_input("enter a number: ")
print testvar
```

Please let me know if there's anything I can do.
Thank you so much in advance,
sectas

Comment: `input()` is working fine for me using a standard install of SublimeREPL on ST2 with Python 3.3 installed on the system. Do you have the latest versions of Sublime Text and SublimeREPL?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. Can you provide a short code example or screenshot? input is also not working. I just freshly installed ST2 and Python 2.7.5 and SublimeREPL today

Comment: `input`() is used in Python 3, `raw_input()` in Python3. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/jCBEnX2) of a very simple program (Py3) in SublimeREPL. This is running in ST2 2.0.2 on Windows XP (my work laptop).

Comment: I see you are running the program per line in a REPL window. What I'd like to do is run the whole file in my regular .py file. Not sure how to solve this but I know it can be done.

Comment: OK, then you need to be clear about that in your question, since SublimeREPL is, by definition, a REPL.

Comment: Hi there. I appreciate your answer, but unfortunately it does not help me move forward. Can you give me any kind of pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the the default build system (Ctrl + B)
If so, open in REPL by:
    `Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python`

If you receive a FileNotFoundError, change the SublimeREPL Settings(USER) to:

    `{
    "default_extend_env": {
        "PATH": "{PATH}:YourDriveLetter:\\YourPath\\Python27\\App\\python.exe"
    }
}`