# Unable to pass user input with Python 2.7 and Sublime 3 in SublimeREPL

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have an issue with SublimeREPL when trying to pass arguments into my python program. I am using python 2.7 with Sublime 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

When I provide SublimeREPL with input and hit enter, nothing happens. It seems to lock up and stop anything thing from happening. I have been looking online to find solutions to this problem and I can't seem to find anything relating to this problem.

Its seems that I need a reputation of 10 to post the image, here is my input

---

```
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
height = raw_input("How tall are you? ")
weight = raw_input("How much do you weigh? ")

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

output on SublimeRepl

---

```
How old are you? 5
10
5
a12d 
user input is not being taken.
```

---

Thank you for your time

Comment: Scratch that, it seems to be [supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921864/sublime-text-2-sublimerepl-allowing-user-input), at least.

Comment: How are you passing your program to SublimeREPL? Which key combo or menu item do you choose? Also, is your `.py` file saved before running it?

Comment: I have SublimeREPL set as my build system, here is my config {
    "target": "run_existing_window_command", 
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}   then I have my sublime window split into two, the left hand side for code and right for SublimeREPL. When I hit ctrl+B it asks for input on the right window. When I hit enter the information is never sent, but makes a newline to keep typing. Also, the files are saved as .py before running.